# Return instancetype in Swift

Tags: swift, swift2, swift-extensions

I'm trying to make this extension:

```
extension UIViewController
{
    class func initialize(storyboardName: String, storyboardId: String) -> Self
    {
        let storyboad = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(storyboardId) as! Self

        return controller
    }
}
```

But I get compile error:

> error: cannot convert return expression of type 'UIViewController' to
>   return type 'Self'

Is it possible? Also I want to make it as `init(storyboardName: String, storyboardId: String)`

Comment: Please don't post answers inside your question.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Similar as in [Using 'self' in class extension functions in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31165535/using-self-in-class-extension-functions-in-swift), you can define a generic helper method which infers the type of self from the calling context:

```
extension UIViewController
{
    class func instantiateFromStoryboard(storyboardName: String, storyboardId: String) -> Self
    {
        return instantiateFromStoryboardHelper(storyboardName, storyboardId: storyboardId)
    }

    private class func instantiateFromStoryboardHelper<T>(storyboardName: String, storyboardId: String) -> T
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(storyboardId) as! T
        return controller
    }
}
```

Then

```
let vc = MyViewController.instantiateFromStoryboard("name", storyboardId: "id")
```

compiles, and the type is inferred as `MyViewController`.

---

Update for **Swift 3:**

```
extension UIViewController
{
    class func instantiateFromStoryboard(storyboardName: String, storyboardId: String) -> Self
    {
        return instantiateFromStoryboardHelper(storyboardName: storyboardName, storyboardId: storyboardId)
    }

    private class func instantiateFromStoryboardHelper<T>(storyboardName: String, storyboardId: String) -> T
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardId) as! T
        return controller
    }
}
```

Another possible solution, using `unsafeDowncast`:

```
extension UIViewController
{
    class func instantiateFromStoryboard(storyboardName: String, storyboardId: String) -> Self
    {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardId)
        return unsafeDowncast(controller, to: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, Could you please explain how the compiler be able to identify the generic type T and be able to cast it to Self?

Comment: people who say "private class func" rather than "static func" have a lot of style.  :)

Comment: it's interesting that if you just have it return the base type - don't bother with a generic - it works perfectly at **runtime** (returning the actual subclass) but you'd have to cast results in code, at "editor time". example: stackoverflow.com/a/42053648/294884

Comment: @JoeBlow: Yes, the goal here was just to avoid the cast. – "static" is "class + final" and therefore unrelated to "private".

Comment: quite. thanks @MartinR.  It took me days to figure the answer to this conceptually similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/42041150/294884

Comment: whoa @MartinR - it appears that:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42161710/can-only-return-not-assign-self

Comment: MartinR, thank you for this great implementation. Since @Adithya's comment asking for clarification had 8 upvotes, I took the liberty to expand a little your response with a quick Further Explanation of your snippet. Feel free to disregard it or edit further.

Comment: I found that this compiles using `static` as well as `class`. I wonder if `class` adds anything.

Comment: @ThomasW: `static == class + final`, i.e. a type method which cannot be overridden in a subclass. So it won't make a difference unless you intend to override it in a subclass.

Comment: @Adithya I think it's because you return `T` in helper method, and return `Self` in instantiate method, so the compiler automatically understand that `T` is `Self`. It's like a chain.

Answer (score 15):

`Self` is determined at compile-time, not runtime. In your code, `Self` is exactly equivalent to `UIViewController`, not "the subclass that happens to be calling this." This is going to return `UIViewController` and the caller will have to `as` it into the right subclass. I assume that's what you were trying to avoid (though it is the "normal Cocoa" way to do it, so just returning `UIViewController` is probably the best solution).

*Note: You should not name the function `initialize` in any case. That's an existing class function of `NSObject` and would cause confusion at best, bugs at worst.*

But if you want to avoid the caller's `as`, subclassing is not usually the tool to add functionality in Swift. Instead, you usually want generics and protocols. In this case, generics are all you need.

```
func instantiateViewController<VC: UIViewController>(storyboardName: String, storyboardId: String) -> VC {
    let storyboad = UIStoryboard(name name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
    let controller = storyboad.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(storyboardId) as! VC

    return controller
}
```

This isn't a class method. It's just a function. There's no need for a class here.

```
let tvc: UITableViewController = instantiateViewController(name: name, storyboardId: storyboardId)
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I had a very similar problem a while back. I wanted a protocol that classes that could be instantiated from a storyboard could implement, so that the caller didn't have to know the exact type of view controller being instantiated. I gave up on that approach. Maybe I'll try it again, but with a generic in the protocol.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner solution (at least visually tidier):

**Swift 5.1**

```
class func initialize(storyboardName: String, storyboardId: String) -> Self {
    UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        .instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardId).view as! Self
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use a protocol, which also allows you to return `Self`.

```
protocol StoryboardGeneratable {

}

extension UIViewController: StoryboardGeneratable {

}

extension StoryboardGeneratable where Self: UIViewController
{
    static func initialize(storyboardName: String, storyboardId: String) -> Self
    {
        let storyboad = UIStoryboard(name: storyboardName, bundle: nil)
        let controller = storyboad.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: storyboardId) as! Self
        return controller
    }
}
```