# How to override init method and return an storyboard instance in swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In Objective-C, I can easily do this use the following codes:

```
- (instancetype)init {
    UIStoryboard *sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    self = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"WMViewController"];
    return self;
}
```

How can I implement this using Swift? 
I know it is strange to do this, but for some reasons, I must init a viewController like the following:

```
let vcClass = WMTableViewController.self
// ...
let vc = vcClass.init()
```

So in order to support `storybord / xib`, it will be easy if can override init method and return another instance.

**Here is the work I am doing:**

I am trying to convert my little lib ([WMPageController](https://github.com/wangmchn/WMPageController)) to Swift ([WMPageController-Swift](https://github.com/wangmchn/WMPageController-Swift)), then I am stucked here.I would be happy if you have another suggestion or solution to deal with it.

**Thanks a lot if you would like to help me.**

Comment: I am not sure if it can be done with an init method, but here is a possible solution using a class method: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33200426/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR: It seems no way to be done with an init method,too bad. :( but thanks for your answer, I get a solution~

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nice question. I tried to solve the same problem in the past.

### A specific solution

First of all you could just use a class method

```
class WMViewController: UIViewController {
    class func loadFromStoryboard() -> WMViewController? {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("WMViewController") as? WMViewController
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
let controller = WMViewController.loadFromStoryboard()
```

### A general solution

However adding the loadFromStoryboard method to each ViewController you want to make "loadable" is a bad practice. So we could move that code inside a protocol extension.

```
protocol StoryboardLoadable { }
extension StoryboardLoadable where Self:UIViewController {
    private static var identifier: String { return "\(Self.self)" }
    static func loadFromStoryboard() -> Self? {
        return UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as? Self
    }
}
```

Now, all you need to do to add the `loadFromStoryboard` method to your custom view controller is this single line

```
extension WMViewController: StoryboardLoadable {}
```

That's it. Now you can load your view controller writing

```
let controller = WMViewController.loadFromStoryboard()
```

Comment: Also a nice solution. I found a different approach some time ago (link below the question).

Comment: What if I have different storyboards and want to apply General Solution?