# How to cast to class type polymorphically in Swift?

Tags: swift, swift3

Here, layEgg() wants to reuse chickenFactory(Chicken.Type). The problem is that layEgg returns Self? so that I get an instance of whatever type this is or nil.

However, chickenFactory returns a Chicken, which needs to be cast to whatever type I am.

```
enum BiologicalGender : String {
    case male = "male"
    case female = "female"
}

class Chicken {
    let gender : BiologicalGender

    required init (_ gender : BiologicalGender) {
        self.gender = gender
    }

    class func chickenFactory(_ chickenType : Chicken.Type) -> Chicken {
        if (arc4random_uniform(2) == 0) {
            return chickenType.init(.male)
        } else {
            return chickenType.init(.female)
        }
    }

    func layEgg() -> Self? {
        if (self.gender == .female) {
            return Chicken.chickenFactory(type(of:self)) // need a cast here
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

How do I cast polymorphically?

Comment: `Self` is not meant to be used in code (cast) only as a return type. It seems if you're comfortable returning the base class from the factory, you're equally comfortable returning the base class from the randomized factory wrapper.

Comment: You have an implicit disagreement between intent and what you expressed. The factory method has only the guarantee that the incoming type meets the minimum requirements of `Chicken` and so must its return type. So when `layEgg()` uses it, it has the same limitation. You can always have: ```class Ficken: Chicken {
    override func layEgg() -> Ficken? {
        return super.layEgg() as? Ficken
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `chickenFactory(_:)` says that it takes a type of type `Chicken.Type` as an argument and outputs an instance of `Chicken`. The instance that is outputted need not be of type the type you passed in (for example, it could output an instance of `Chicken` when you input a type of `ChickenSubclass.self`).

What you want is not type-casting, but rather a way to say that the instance outputted is the *same* type as the type you input. To express this, you can use a generic placeholder:

```
class func chickenFactory<T : Chicken>(_ chickenType : T.Type) -> T {
    if (arc4random_uniform(2) == 0) {
        return chickenType.init(.male)
    } else {
        return chickenType.init(.female)
    }
}
```

Now

```
func layEgg() -> Self? {
    if (self.gender == .female) {
        return Chicken.chickenFactory(type(of: self))
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

compiles just fine, as the compiler knows that an instance of type `type(of: self)` can be returned from a function returning `Self?`.

Although that all being said, the type argument to `chickenFactory(_:)` is seemingly redundant, you could just use the type that it's called on instead through the use of `self` at static scope:

```
class func chickenFactory() -> Self {
    if (arc4random_uniform(2) == 0) {
        return self.init(.male)
    } else {
        return self.init(.female)
    }
}

func layEgg() -> Self? {
    if (self.gender == .female) {
        return type(of: self).chickenFactory()
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: This fixes the code by removing the need to cast to Self or "whatever type this object is". One could still imagine the need to cast this way, but it may be impossible (unsafe?).

Comment: @MikeJfromVA I don't *believe* there is a way to cast to `Self` (there are a lot of restrictions around the use of it) – but in almost all cases there is usually a solution to the problem which utilises static typing rather than runtime type-casting. The latter should only be used to express relations that can't be expressed by the type-system.

Comment: I stand corrected – there is actually a way to cast to `Self` through the use of a generic helper function, [as shown by Martin's answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200035/return-instancetype-in-swift/33200426#33200426) – although, as I've said, this is unnecessary for your use case. Your factory method can express the relationship directly.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution for the problem would be this. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33200426/3066450)

```
func layEgg() -> Self? {
    if (self.gender == .female) {
        return makeEgg()
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}

func makeEgg<T>()->T?{
    return Chicken.chickenFactory(type(of:self)) as? T
}
```

Comment: But then we remove the idea of a factory pattern, which is inherently a `class func`

Comment: @Hamish `makeEgg()` is only specific for the class `Chicken` and will always return only the instance of `self` as far as I know. I tried creating an object of `Chicken` and called the function `layEgg()` and I didn't encounter any crash.

Comment: @Hamish Yes, check the updated answer. I guess that rules out the probable crash :)

Answer (score 0):

This does not necessarily improve the code, but here is a class function wrapping the original factory that accomplishes the cast to Self that so many of you demonstrated.

The original, improved generic chickenFactory() is also included.

```
class Chicken {
    let gender : BiologicalGender

    required init (_ gender : BiologicalGender) {
        self.gender = gender
    }

    class func chickenFactory<T:Chicken>(_ chickenType : T.Type) -> T {
        if (arc4random_uniform(2) == 0) {
            return chickenType.init(.male)
        } else {
            return chickenType.init(.female)
        }
    }

    class func poorlyTypedChickenFactory(_ chickenType : Chicken.Type) -> Chicken {
        if (arc4random_uniform(2) == 0) {
            return chickenType.init(.male)
        } else {
            return chickenType.init(.female)
        }
    }

    private class func chickenFromPoorlyTypedFactory<T>(_ chickenType : Chicken.Type) -> T?
    {
        let chicken = poorlyTypedChickenFactory(chickenType) as? T
        return chicken
    }

    func layEgg() -> Self? {
        if (self.gender == .female) {
            return Chicken.chickenFromPoorlyTypedFactory(type(of:self))
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In the function `chickenFromPoorlyTypedFactory `, change the return type from `T` to `T?` and similarly change `as! T` inside that function to `as? T`. This way even if you call this function inside the class in the place of another type it will just return nil instead of crashing.