# Cannot convert return expression of type 'child' to return type T

Tags: swift, generics

I am struggling a bit with generics in Swift.

I have the following code:

```
class Parent {
    init(value: SomeThing) {
        // ...
    }

    func clone<T: Parent>() -> T {        
        return T(value: SomeThing)
    }
}

class Child : Parent {
    var otherValue: SomeThingElse?

    override func clone<T>() -> T where T : Parent {        
        let clone: Child = super.clone()
        clone.otherValue = self.otherValue
        return clone  //ERROR: cannot convert return expression of type 'Child' to return type T
    }
}
```

The idea is to create a simple method that returns a new copy of a child instance with identical values. 
I don't want to write the constructor out for each Child classtype. (it has a lot of params in the real classes, and I like to keep it clean).

The error I get is:
`cannot convert return expression of type 'Child' to return type T`
Suggested solution is to make it `return clone as! T`. But that way I lose the reason to use a generic class.

Any idea how to solve this while keeping it generic and not write out the constructor in each class?

Comment: You should consider using value types (`struct`). Value types are copied on assignment so you don't have to do that manually. You would lose the ability to subclass, but you can use protocols and extensions to work around that.

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use struct, since the class also needs to be used in Objective-C.

Comment: If your class is an NSObject subclass, you can use [NSCopying](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nscopying).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have a return type of `Self`, rather than using a generic placeholder constrained to `Parent`. With the generic placeholder, you're saying that `clone()` can return an instance of *any* specific concrete type that inherits from `Parent`. However that's not true – you only want to return instances of the *same* type as the receiver, which is what `Self` expresses.

You'll then also need to implement a `required` initialiser so that it's available to call on all subclasses, allowing `clone()` to be called on them without them necessarily overriding it.

```
struct Something {}
struct SomethingElse {}

class Parent {

    var something: Something

    required init(something: Something) {
        self.something = something
    }

    func clone() -> Self {
        // call the initialiser on the dynamic metatype of the instance,
        // ensuring that we're instantiating a Self instance.
        return type(of: self).init(something: something)
    }
}
```

The implementation of `Child` then *should* be as simple as:

```
class Child : Parent {

    var somethingElse: SomethingElse?

    override func clone() -> Self {
        let clone = super.clone()
        clone.somethingElse = somethingElse
        return clone
    }
}
```

However unfortunately, calling `clone()` on `super` returns an instance that's statically typed as `Parent` rather than `Self` – this has been [filed as a bug](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-1736).

To workaround this, you'll have to do some force casting hackery:

```
override func clone() -> Self {

    let clone = super.clone() as! Child
    clone.somethingElse = somethingElse

    func forceCast<T>(_ value: Child) -> T { return value as! T }
    return forceCast(clone)
}
```

The nested `forceCast(_:)` function is here to workaround the fact that we currently cannot directly cast to `Self` in a method (compare [Return instancetype in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33200035/2976878)). Both the force casts in this case will always succeed because `super.clone()` will always return a `Self` instance, which therefore must be a `Child` in this method.

Comment: Interesting. If it where not for the bug requiring the forceCast, I would use this. But currently it looks uglier then just returning `clone as! T`. Hope this gets fixed! For now I will accept, since it looks like the proper way to do it, bugs withstanding.

Comment: @Peterdk The problem with doing `as! T` in your original code is that it can crash for when the instance isn't castable to `T`. Consider if you had `class Foo : Parent {}`, and then had an instance of `Child` called `child`. Doing `let foo: Foo = child.clone()` would crash, as an instance of `Child` cannot be cast to `Foo`. The benefit of using a return type of `Self` is that the compiler knows that for a `Child` instance, calling `clone()` on it will return a `Child` instance. It's just a shame it doesn't currently know this for when calling it on `super` :/

Comment: ok, that situation won't occur in my situation. I agree that using Self is a better option, but don't like the extra hoops I need to code for.