# type casting when creating an instance from a parent class

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to ask something about type-casting in Swift.

There are 2 classes.

1. `RootViewController`
2. `MyViewController`

and the class hierarchy is like below:

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {

}

class MyViewController: RootViewController {

}
```

and, I want to simply call `instance` function to create an instance from xib file.
so I implemented below function in `RootViewController`.

Objective-C

```
+ (instancetype)instance {
    return [[[self class] alloc] initWithNibName:NSStringFromClass([self class]) bundle:nil];
}
```

Swift

```
public class func instance<T:RootViewController>() -> T {
    let type = self as UIViewController.Type
    let name = NSStringFromClass(type).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
    let instance = type.init(nibName: name, bundle: nil)
    return instance as! T
}
```

and, usage is like below.

Objective-C

```
MyViewController *vc = [MyViewController instance];
```

Swift

```
let vc = MyViewController.instance() as! MyViewController
```

**Question:**

Do I have to always cast the type of instance using `as! MyViewController` in Swift?
Or can anybody advise me a better approach in Swift?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't see any problem or question here. I would personally avoid using `instance` or any other factory methods in swift, because you can't use `Self` as a return type. Use regular `init` methods instead.

Comment: It is better to use "as?" instead of "as!"  for casting.

Comment: And, I must add, this question is better to be asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Compare [Return instancetype in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33200035/2976878) – you want a return type of `Self`, using a generic helper function in order to perform the cast.

Comment: Check my answer it eliminates casting at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class RootViewController: UIViewController {
    public class func instance() -> Self {
        func inner<T: RootViewController>(type: T.Type) -> T {
            let name = NSStringFromClass(type).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
            let type1 = type as UIViewController.Type
            let instance = type1.init(nibName: name, bundle: nil)
            return instance as! T
        }
        return inner(type: self)
    }
}
```

I would suggest creating an extension method:

```
extension UIViewController {
    public class func instance() -> Self {
        func inner<T: UIViewController>(type: T.Type) -> T {
            let name = NSStringFromClass(type).components(separatedBy: ".").last!
            return T(nibName: name, bundle: nil)
        }
        return inner(type: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't even compile.

Comment: @kelin As if OP's does.

Comment: @kelin check now.

Comment: @OrkhanAlikhanov, now I'm getting the following error:  "Cannot convert value of type 'Self.Type' to expected argument type 'RootViewController.Type'"

Comment: @kelin weird I am not getting it.

Comment: @kelin Although I was not getting that error, I removed the usage of `self` from the `inner` method.  Can you try now?

Comment: @kelin I run it and it failed to cast, fixed. Now working.

Answer (score 3):

You can Also use like this way

```
let vc:MyViewController = MyViewController.instance()
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay you can instantiate in these three ways:

1. Swift inference to `Type`:

   ```
   let myVC = RootViewController.instance()   //Swift will automatically infer the type
   ```
2. Explicitly telling the `Type`:

   ```
   let myVC: RootViewController = RootViewController.instance()
   ```
3. Casting to your `Type`:

   ```
   let myVC = RootViewController.instance() as! RootViewController
   ```

All these three are valid.