# Pass a type as variable

Tags: ios, swift

How do I go about passing a Type as a variable in Swift 4?

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MapViewController") as! MapViewController
```

I have something similar to the above in a horrible if statement I'd like to move to a function, but not sure how I pass 'MapViewController' (or whatever the controller is as a variable).

'"Pseduo" Code'

```
function setVC(withViewController : Any) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MapViewController") as! withViewController
}
```

Comment: Why do you need that? Why do you have to do "as" ? They should all inherits from `UIViewController`.

Comment: You sir make a very good point. It works without... (I'm still getting my head around certain things - That was a mish-mash of a few tutorials).

What use case would there be to specify 'as' manually?

Comment: Because you want to set some properties of your VC (knowing its classes, and so its public properties).

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200035/return-instancetype-in-swift.

Answer (score 0):

You could use generic parameters like here:

```
function setVC<T>(withViewController: T) {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MapViewController") as! T
}
```

Comment: Actually such as solution was already suggested in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/33200294/1187415 to the question that I linked to above :)

Comment: Oh sorry didn't checked the comments. Yes thats the way how it works.