# How can I return instancetype in Swift from instance method

Tags: objective-c, swift

Consider method like this:

```
- (instancetype)sizeFit {
    [self sizeToFit];
    return self;
}
```

It’s useful for method chaining, I have whole api written like this in my framework and wanted to move it to Swift, searched here questions but found just some complicated answers instead of no, it’s not possible in normal readable way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very short answer is no there is no direct equivalent.

The more detailed answer is that the languages are conceptually different.

- In Objective-C anything returned is an object aka `id`. Using `instancetype` is a hint to the compiler and IDE for a specific type to allow further checks and auto-completion. This works for sub-classing and extensions.
- Swift is strongly typed, there is no base object and we also have classes and structs. A function can only return a specific type, `Self`, a generic type or an `associatedtype`. The best approximation would be to move this functionality into an `extension` or `protocol` and use `Self`. This would work the same way. There is no equivalent for this in a sub classing context.

Long detailed answer [Return instancetype in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33200035/return-instancetype-in-swift)

Comment: Ok I got it so extension can do it the same/similar way .... in sub-classing its not possible, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, so in short, this is equivalent way in swift to return instance type:

```
extension UIView {
    func someFunctionThatReturnInstanceTypeInAllSubclassesOfView() -> Self {
        return self
    }
}
```

It wont work in classes though.

Comment: That works well in extensions. One can see that for protocol extensions in the standard library.